# Bullet 2.81: Unable to find installed header?

Tags: c++, compilation, ubuntu-12.04, header-files, bulletphysics

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

I've installed Bullet Physics from source, and am attempting to

`#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>` from a source file.

When I compile the source file, I get the following error...

`error: btBulletDynamicsCommon.h: No such file or directory`

The following is an excerpt from my terminal...

```
uberblah@uberblah-N80Vm:~$ locate btBulletDynamicsCommon.h
/home/uberblah/lib/cpp/Bullet/bullet-2.81-rev2613/src/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h
/usr/local/include/bullet/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h
/usr/local/include/bullet/BulletDynamics/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h
```

Is there a particular reason the compiler wouldn't be finding the header?

It should be noted that I am using Code::Blocks to do the building, although the same error is received if I try to put that include in a source file and then compile it using a my own Makefile (I don't actually reference any of the functions from the header, so there's no need to link the libraries).

Comment: Most compilers I've used don't look in `/usr/local/include` by default. Just add it to your include search path.

Comment: Shouldn't it already be on the search path? Which environment variable is this "search path"?

Comment: I don't know where the setting is in Code::Blocks, but the command line flag for gcc and clang would be `-I/usr/local/include`

Comment: I'd really like to have that automatically added to the include path from here on out, instead of having to specify it every time. Is there a way I can permanently add it to the search path?

EDIT: It appears that adding -I/usr/local/include does not help!

Comment: Not that I know of. You should be able to just set it once in Code::Blocks, your Makefile or whatever build system and not have to worry about it again though.

Comment: well, using -I/usr/local/include/bullet did the trick, but it's a disappointing result, because I'm using bullet for several projects. If there's a way to permanently add it to the include search directories, tell me. Otherwise, this problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "/usr/local/include" to 'Settings > Compiler and Debugger > Global compiler settings (on left) > Search directories' and use

```
#include <bullet/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>
```

This way when you want to use other headers in /usr/local/include, you don't have to keep adding the individual directories.